# White page in flutter when hosting

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I want to display an alert dialog that is called as follows:[image: CustomDialogoTarjeta call]

And the CustomDialogoTarjeta code is:
[image: Part 1 of the class]
[image: Part 2]
`

```
Widget buildCard2(BuildContext context) {
    String color = "Rosa";
    return Positioned(
      top: 50,
      left: Consts.padding,
      right: Consts.padding * 2,
      bottom: 0,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: secondBgColor,
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Consts.padding),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color.fromARGB(66, 0, 0, 0),
              blurRadius: 10.0,
              offset: const Offset(0.0, 10.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: Consts.avatarRadius + Consts.padding,
          bottom: 0, //Consts.avatarRadius + Consts.padding,
          left: Consts.avatarRadius + Consts.padding,
          right: Consts.avatarRadius + Consts.padding,
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: Consts.avatarRadius, bottom: 0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // To make the card compact
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              "Añade una tarea",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            TextFormField(
              controller: nombreController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Introduzca el nombre de la tarea',
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: fechaController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Introduzca la fecha de finalización de la tarea',
              ),
            ),
            RadioButtonWidget(
              // dont use const
              onRadioButtonChanged: (value) {
                color = value!;
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: const Text('Cancelar'),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  //here I do the search in firebase database
                  MenuController m = MenuController();
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      // Pass ViewModel down to EditScreen

                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return MaterialApp(
                        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                        title: 'iOrganize',
                        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
                          scaffoldBackgroundColor: secondBgColor,
                          textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(
                                  Theme.of(context).textTheme)
                              .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white),
                          canvasColor: fisrtBgColor,
                        ),
                        home: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                          value: m,
                          child: PrincipalView(usuario: usuario),
                        ));
                  }));
                },
                child: const Text('Añadir'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
```

`

This works perfectly when I do flutter run, but when I do the host with firebase I get the white screen caused by the following error:
[image: Error]

I try the scafoll, then I tried to see which part of the code gives the error, but it is impossible.
The js that gives the error cannot be modified by hand, because when I run the commands for the firebase hosting it overrides it

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content (such as error messages and stack traces). Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, i need to solve the white page error and make the page show the dialog